# Structure element test to null

Tags: c, struct, null, zero

I want to test an element for `structure` if he is empty or not 
but when (ex.) the `G[s].a=0` and `G[s].b=2`
he never go into the `if` ,, any help ?

```
 if (G[s].a != NULL && G[s].b != NULL)
```

Comment: Why do you expect the code to enter the `if` statement if `G[s].a==0`? NULL and 0 are guaranteed to be compatible and have the same meaning when it comes to pointers (both give a null pointer).

Comment: i want to test if an element is different to -858993460 and in my programme i want the zero be like a normal integer

Comment: Umm... and how does that make any sense, given the code you have posted?

Comment: How is the `struct` declared? I can't see how you can test `G[s].b == 2` and `G[s].b != NULL` without getting a compiler warning.

Comment: the compiler are fine but the zero and NULL are the same in c so i do that "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"

Comment: `0` and `NULL` are only the same when they are pointer values. Assigning `NULL` to an `int` gives a compiler warning, as does testing if an `int` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re write your logic with positive logic instead of using not null.

"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".